# Formal systems for physical theory

Tags: logic, reference-request, mathematical-physics

Are there any attempt to express a part of physical theory, for example, Newtonian mechanics,  in the form of a formal system such as first-order or higher-order predicate logic?

Comment: Yes. Robert Israel has already mentioned Hilbert. Other interesting papers here are Herbert Simon ("The Axioms of Newtonian Mechanics"), McKinsey, Sugar, and Suppes ("Axiomatic Foundations of Classical Particle Mechanics"), Mario Bunge ("The Axiomatic Method in Physics"). Katherine Brading and Leo Corry have important scholarship on Hilbert's axiomatics. See also "rational mechanics."

Comment: See : Joseph Sneed, [The Logical Structure of Mathematical Physics](https://books.google.it/books?id=vqH6CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1971).

Comment: About [Joseph Sneed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_D._Sneed) and the [structural theory of the empirical sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuralism_(philosophy_of_science)) see also [Wolfgang Stegmüller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Stegm%C3%BCller).

Comment: See also [Constantin Carathéodory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantin_Carath%C3%A9odory), ["Untersuchungen ueber die Grundlagen der Thermodynamik" (Examination of the foundations of Thermodynamics)](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnzej7vILRAhVhKsAKHYqdCWQQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fneo-classical-physics.info%2Fuploads%2F3%2F0%2F6%2F5%2F3065888%2Fcaratheodory_-_thermodynamics.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGvEQkMjkdf12InNijU35LttX15Hw) (1909).

Comment: Also [Clifford Truesdell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_Truesdell), [Foundations of Continuum Mechanics](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-86102-4_4) (1967).

Comment: I don't think are "axioms" in science. There are only tentative, hypothetical relationships between physical variables subject to empirical testing and ongoing revision.

Comment: @Dan Christensen: obviously science is not pure mathematics. But axiomatizing a physical theory can be useful to reveal its logical structure, to clarify conceptual relationships, to deduce new predictions, etc. Both Newtonian and quantum mechanics are often taught this way: starting from some empirically justified axioms, deduce nonobvious consequences.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Would you call Newton's law of gravity (the famous equation)  an "axiom?"  How about $F=ma$?

Comment: @Dan: you've missed the point. I encourage you to read some of the literature cited here.

Comment: I take it they aren't axioms in the usual sense of the word. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, essentially, [Hilbert's sixth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixth_problem):

> Mathematical Treatment of the Axioms of Physics. The investigations on the foundations of geometry suggest the problem: To treat in the same manner, by means of axioms, those physical sciences in which already today mathematics plays an important part; in the first rank are the theory of probabilities and mechanics.

Comment: Relevant : Leo Corry, [David Hilbert and the Axiomatization of Physics (1898–1918): From Grundlagen der Geometrie to Grundlagen der Physik](https://books.google.it/books?id=G3caBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2004).